# How to mention rootfs in manifest file?

Tags: cloud-foundry, diego

During staging process of an artifact by Pivotal Cloud Foundry, it picks the **rootfs** and **buildpack** details before staging an application instance in Diego container.

Buildpack details can be mentioned in manifest file

Can we also mention rootfs details in `manifest.yml`?

Comment: See https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html, which lists what you can put in the manifest, and https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/stacks.html, which tells you how to specify a stack when you push. Note also that a key point of the PaaS abstraction from the dev perspective is [i do not care how](https://twitter.com/onsijoe/status/598235841635360768?s=21).

Comment: This is a duplicate of the other question you asked -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54599886/cloudfoundry-how-to-understand-the-operating-systemos-environment-of-an-app

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CloudFoundry - How to understand the operating system(OS) environment of an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54599886/cloudfoundry-how-to-understand-the-operating-systemos-environment-of-an-app)